# VirtualBox installation in Ubuntu 14.04, throws an input output error

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install VirtualBox and I keep getting this error message in XTERM (and the Ubuntu Software Center) when I do `sudo apt-get install VirtualBox`:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libgnutls26:amd64': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: What does a `sudo apt-get update` do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dpkg fatal error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717281/dpkg-fatal-error)