# Dpkg fatal error

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am using UbuntuMATE 15.10, on a Lenovo X201 tablet.
I try to update my system, with:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

The system read the packages that need to be updated, it download them, but it doesn't install the required updates, showing the following error:

`dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
reading files list for package "gnuplot-data": input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`

At the same time, I am unable to install any new software.

What does it mean? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to solve on the Ubuntu italian forum:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/gnuplot-data*
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq gnuplot-data
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Source: http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=606310&p=4840071#p4840071