# Problem with installing and removing packages in ubuntu

Tags: apt, dpkg, sudo

I am running ubuntu for the first time in my life. I am able to update the packages easily. But I can't remove or install packages/software(anything using *sudo apt-get install or remove*). Here is the output on entering an install/remove command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  blt idle-python3.5 python3-tk tk8.6-blt2.5
Suggested packages:
  blt-demo tix python3-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  blt idle-python3.5 idle3 python3-tk tk8.6-blt2.5
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 345 not upgraded.
Need to get 647 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,345 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 tk8.6-blt2.5 amd64 2.5.3+dfsg-3 [574 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 blt amd64 2.5.3+dfsg-3 [4,852 B]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-tk amd64 3.5.1-1 [25.1 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 idle-python3.5 all 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1 [40.5 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 idle3 all 3.5.1-3 [2,800 B]
Fetched 647 kB in 5s (121 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package tk8.6-blt2.5.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'anacron': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

And here are the solutions I have already tried and there is no success.

[How to fix dpkg error [2]?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603295/how-to-fix-dpkg-error-2)

This thread is telling about editing 'status' section, where the 'anacron'  is mentioned, but there is only 1 line that mentions this package.

Here is that line:

```
Recommends: apport-gtk (>= 2.8-0ubuntu3), python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets | synaptic (>= 0.75.12), software-properties-gtk, anacron, python3-aptdaemon
```

After that another package is started.

Also, I have tried this thread but no success:
[How can I fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2)

Hope, I will be able to find some help here.

Thanks,

Comment: You showed error messages that you won't get for the 10's of thousands of packages available in the repository.  **We need to see the command you typed in** to produce the error.  The errors will depend on what was typed in to bring them.  If you typed `sudo apt install vlc` that package is available and will install.  YOu will also be able to remove that package using `sudo apt remove vlc`.  If you try to install something that isn't available, or is broken because of something you have done it's show you the appropriate errors.

Comment: This issue is coming forward with any command which involve install or remove with sudo. To be specific, I am trying:

    sudo apt-get install idle3

Comment: **Can you show us one specific command that you are issuing.**  Then show the output of that one command.  We can address the issue with that one command.  Once the issue with that one command is resolved, there is a chance it will clear up other issues.  But we can't address and issue when we can't see the command that brought it own.  Will you run this command and show us the output?  **`sudo apt install vlc`**?

Comment: I can provide you with a resolution that will install that application if you show the command and the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dpkg fatal error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717281/dpkg-fatal-error)