# reading files list for package 'texlive-base': Input/output error

Tags: 14.04, apt

When I try to install anything, it fails with error message:

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package ladspa-sdk.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'texlive-base': Input/output error
```

This is not a duplicate question: 
Below is the message that appears at the end and if I install anything, below error appears:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'texlive-base': Input/output error
```

Disk or partition is not full.

Comment: The "'texlive-base': Input/output error" suggests your partition may be full.

Comment: @Panther: Not quite. Reading files should be indifferent to full file systems. It points to a failing drive though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/539184/how-do-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-storage-medium-hard-disk-or-flash-drive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dpkg fatal error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717281/dpkg-fatal-error)