# How to repair apt-get? libacl1 missing, reading files list for package 'libcdparanoia0:amd64': Input/output error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am unable to install any package. First it was message about libacl1 package: 
    reading files list for package 'libacl1:amd64': Input/output error

And I deleted all flies, related to libacl1:amd64 in irder ti reinstall it, but when I tried to reinstall libacl1, error about libcdparanoia0 appears.

When reinstall linux-image-generic, I faced the same error:

```
nadezhda@nadezhda-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall -f linux-image-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools linux-headers-4.4.0-138-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 215 not upgraded.
Need to get 60,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 226 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 iucode-tool amd64 1.5.1-1ubuntu0.1 [33,8 kB]
Get:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic amd64 4.4.0-138.164 [22,1 MB]
Get:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic amd64 4.4.0-138.164 [36,6 MB]                                                                      
Get:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 intel-microcode amd64 3.20180807a.0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1 275 kB]                                                                          
Get:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 amd64-microcode amd64 3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.16.04.2 [32,2 kB]                                                                           
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 4.4.0.138.144 [2 382 B]                                                                                      
Fetched 60,1 MB in 22s (2 711 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                        
Selecting previously unselected package iucode-tool.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libacl1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libcdparanoia0:amd64': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Please, help! How to restore dpkg?

Comment: "Input/output error" is not an apt error. It's usually a hardware error. Look up how to run a 'SMART test' on your storage device.

Comment: Its Virtual Box machine, not real one

Comment: Seems like a great question for [VirtualBox support](http://forums.virtualbox.org), since that is what is emulating the hardware.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dpkg fatal error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717281/dpkg-fatal-error)